# subprocess.run does not work with cwd argument

Tags: python

When I attempt to run a basic shell script with the `subprocess` module, I cannot seem to get it running without specifying the absolute path to my script. That is:

```
proc = run(['classify.sh', twitter_handle],
           cwd='/Users/kkworden/Code/school/Twirole',
           stdout=PIPE)
```

Does not work, but:

```
proc = run(['/Users/kkworden/Code/school/Twirole/classify.sh', twitter_handle],
           stdout=PIPE)
```

Does work. Why? Shouldn't the two be the same?

Comment: Hmm, [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) states that "In particular, the function looks for *executable* (or for the first item in *args*) relative to *cwd* if the executable path is a relative path." and yet it clearly doesn't do that. I guess it's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I forgot to specify the script relatively:

```
proc = run(['./classify.sh', twitter_handle],
           cwd='/Users/kkworden/Code/school/Twirole',
           stdout=PIPE)
```

Notice the leading `./` before my script.